# How to run method that will execute before hydrate in django-tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

I need the following logic:
User is posting objects to server, but I need that objects he posted earlier would be deleted before new objects were created.
Is there some method, that is called e.g. before hydrate() method, in which I could get access  to authorized user object?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem concerns creation, then you could override obj_create method. It's given the request object so you can access request.user there. Something like this should work for you:

```
class SomeResource( ... ):

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        user = request.user if request else None
        # ...
        if user:
            # delete objects here
        # ...
        super( SomeResource, self ).obj_create( bundle, request, **kwargs )
```

Comment: obj_create will run for each object, and I need to run this code only once, at start of request processing...

Comment: Then override dispatch() and put your code somewhere before "response = method(request, **kwargs)". You also have request there, but it runs once per request.

Comment: Yeah, that could work. Also I found another way: override patch_list(). Unfortunately, either in dispatch() or in patch_list(), I have request object before authorization is made - so I don't have User object there. But it partially solves my problem.

Comment: dispatch() performs authentication and authorization, so perhaps if you added your code in a proper place it would work (after auth)? The other idea I got is to modify obj_create() (which is logically a good place) but to have a flag somewhere which denotes whether this is a first or not creation in given request (to avoid the issue with multiple calls you mentioned). Hope this helps :)